# What's wrong with EA.com account and Polish tld?

Tags: technical-issues, origin

**tl;dr** *Origin client for Windows 10 blocks creation of child account claiming that provided parent's email address (which belongs to an existing account) is invalid. It seems that the problem is because that parent's email address is in Polish (.pl) top-level domain (ccTLD).*

*Does anyone heard anything about such weird problem? Is this something common or is it only me?*

*What should I do in this case, if I don't want to / can't use different email (i.e. with non-Polish ccTLD)?*

---

I cannot enrol new *child* EA.com / Origin account because it claims that my (parent) email address (that I've been using for past 17 years) is invalid.

[image]

As I managed to figure out, the .pl (Polish top-level domain) is the problem. My Gmail's address passes without any troubles.

The story goes as:

1. I have tried to register new account using newest stable version of Chrome browser for Windows. That failed (left above). For some reason using exactly the same URL I managed to enroll an account using Edge for Windows 10.
2. Then my daughter installed Origin client for Windows 10 and tried to register child account, by providing my email address and her password (as instructed [here](https://help.ea.com/en-us/help/account/set-up-child-ea-account/)). And we hit the wall for the second time.

This is twice stupid. Not only EA stuff (website) claims that a perfectly valid email address is invalid, but also EA software (Origin client) claims that already existing account's<sup>1</sup> email address is invalid.

**Is there anything I can do in this case? Except for using another email address (i.e. without Polish ccTLD), which I'd like to avoid as much as this is possible. How to enroll a child account into existing parent's account if Origin client claims that parent account's email is invalid?**

I did some research, but all that I managed to find out was [some dully post](https://itfuckup.com/2021/05/15/electronic-arts-hates-poland/) that reports above, but brings no resolution to described problem.

<sup>1</sup><sub>I can login to my account anytime and when I am doing so, it is magically no longer invalid.</sub>

**EDIT**: *The issue is with Polish (.pl) domain in general. I have five .pl email addresses and all of them suffers this way. I have a single non-dot-pl email address and it goes without any problems.*

Comment: I sympathize ... but what exactly is your question? I'm having difficulty figuring out what you're trying to ask.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Damn... I thought this is pretty much straightforward. The question is: "_What should I do in this case?_". How can I tell to Origin client for Windows something like that: "_Hey man, you're blatantly stupid! That parent's email address belongs to an already existing EA account, so the hell it cannot be invalid. Continue and stop making an idiot out of yourself!_". :) BTW: Question edited to make this more clear.

Comment: Lol fair enough. Though if it is a bug with the client you may have more luck tweeting at EA or otherwise contacting them directly. :)

Comment: Your dealing with a computer application that follows a very specific set of instructions. If a field doesn't accept your email, there isn't much we can do. EA need to physically update the software to include your email domain as a valid domain. What is the domain, exactly? (Everything after the @ symbol). Is there a reason you can't use your Gmail account, apart from not wanting to?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Any idea how can I "tweet" EA? I don't think you're talking about actually tweeting them through Twitter since I am more than sure that they're getting like hundreds of thousands of messages like that each day and I am pretty sure that my tweet will be ignored. Any bug tracker that you could possible point me to?

Comment: Nah I was actually referring to Twitter. Companies like this generally have pr/media teams watching their Twitter feeds to respond to actual issues. Same with a company Facebook page. A "hey your app doesn't recognize my valid example.pl email; how am I supposed to create an account for my kid?" sort of thing is what I was suggesting -- but an actual tweet not a DM.

Comment: @Gnemlock As in edited question. No, its not about "everything after @ symbol", its actually about Polish (.pl) domain at all, as I have tested this thorough file different Polish email addresses and all of them are rejected. The reason of not using Gmail address is weak / simple -- I already have a parent account that I'd like to use / re-use instead of registering a new one. But, ultimately I most likely finish using Gmail account.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I went [this way](https://answers.ea.com/t5/Origin-Client-Web-Technical/EA-account-and-Origin-for-PC-rejects-Polish-pl-email-addresses/m-p/10413401#M114319)

Answer (score 2):

Confirmed as a bug inside EA account support and Origin app for Windows 10 that Gaming Stack Exchange community cannot help with.

### Problem no 1 (cannot register EA Account with .pl email address)

If you are stuck with first problem in question (i.e. you cannot register parent account and changing Chrome to Edge or any other browser does not help) then you must click the [Get help from an advisor without logging in](https://help.ea.com/uk/contact-us/?product=origin&platform=pc&category=report-a-bug&issue=report-bug&isLoginForm=true&isContactForm=true) link to continue. This will ask you for your name etc. and then will redirect you to... Answers HQ, so you hit the wall again.

By using old-good Google I managed to find [this page](https://help.ea.com/uk/search/?product=origin&platform=pc&category=report-a-bug&community=true), but ultimately it led me back to the above -- after clicking through you finally land at login page prior contacting EA). So, if you cannot create an account, because your email is falsely claimed as invalid then you're realy stuck. Because, to report that you cannot register an account you must... login to an account.

### Problem no 2 (have parent account; can't bind child account to)

The [Let us know about problems with a game or your EA Account](https://help.ea.com/en-gb/help/faq/report-problems-with-games-or-ea-account/) page says:

> From EA Help, you can report a bug or give feedback by clicking [Contact Us](https://help.ea.com/uk/contact-us/), choosing a game and platform, then selecting the Report a bug category. Depending on your game, we might direct you to Answers HQ or ask you to email us.

After clicking through all the options (i.e. *Origin app > For PC > Report a bug > Report a bug*) you are finally redirected to the [Select contact option](https://help.ea.com/uk/contact-us/?product=origin&platform=pc&category=report-a-bug&issue=report-bug) page. You must login in order to continue and after you do so, you are... redirected to Answer HQ and you hit the wall again.

### Summary

Using non-Polish email address seems to be the only option in this case. It seems that EA has a huge bug in their system.

Or you may try to use Answers HQ, like [I did](https://answers.ea.com/t5/Origin-Client-Web-Technical/EA-account-and-Origin-for-PC-rejects-Polish-pl-email-addresses/m-p/10413401#M114319).